# Removing 3.5inch touchscreen and going back to HDMI out

Tags: raspbian, gpio, hdmi, touchscreen

I installed a 3.5inch touchscreen onto my pi 3 model b+, it came with a wee card of the setup lines etc.

That was sometime ago, and now I need to revert the system back to being HDMI output.

I’ve done a fair bit of research and constantly end up back at /boot/config.txt but with no luck.

When it comes to the pi I tend to workout just enough to make it do what I’d like it too, I never remember quite how I’ve done it and always need to search for the answers..hoping you guys can help me out with an idiots guide just for me..

The screen mounts on to the GPIO pins, and the OS is Raspbian

Thanks in advance 
Damo

Comment: There are many many screens - do you have info on the one you purchased?  Without that its going to be hard to say what to do.  My guess is that drivers are loaded in config.txt and commenting them out and adding the default HDMI settings will reset the output for you.  It would also help if you posted the config.txt here.

Comment: I don’t, I do have the commands used to initialise the screen somewhere if that may help? I’ll find them. I’ll also get a copy of the config.txt and post it here also.

Comment: Any reason you can’t just reflash your sd card?

Comment: Screen seems to be LCDWiki.

Comment: And no actually, no reason at all I can’t just flash the card..